# How can I run a callback when I know all asynchronous calls have been completed?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, three.js

I am making an application using Three.js, to create a textual geometry and add it to the scene, I pass a function. However, I can do this several times and I have created a method that iterates over all meshes in the scene and performs some visual changes. My Question is, how can I know when all async calls have completed and I know all meshes have been added to the scene, such that when I call my method and iterate over all meshes in the scene, all meshes have been successfully added?

e.g.

```
/* Create the scene Text */
let loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
loader.load('fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', font => {
    /* Create the geometry */
    let geometry_text = new THREE.TextGeometry("example text");

    /* Currently using basic material because I do not have a light, Phong will be black */
    let material_text = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();

    let textMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry_text, material_text);
    scene.add(textMesh);  // <---------- Adds the mesh to the scene

});

fade_meshes_into_scene();      // <------- iterates over all meshes in scene.
```

In this example, It will not work since `fade_meshes_into_scene` iterates over all meshes in the scene and in this case the scene will have no meshes because it's called before `scene.add(textMesh)` is called. However, I can move it inside the async call when I only do it once, but will fail to work when I add multiple text and different async calls.

**How can I know when I have added all of my meshes so I know when to call** `fade_meshes_into_scene`?

Comment: So are you saying you'll have many `loader.load` functions?

Comment: I only have one in my application currently, so I have moved `fade_meshes_into_scene` inside for now, however in the future I want to use different fonts etc, I will have to have multiple. So yea, I will have to use multiple loader.load

Comment: Okay, I'll answer from that perspective!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you turn your font loading into Promises. You can then use `Promise.all` to guarantee that all promises in an array have resolved before executing the function you pass to `then`!.

```
const loadFont = fontPath => {
  return new Promise(res => {
    loader.load(fontPath, font => {
      // do loading things
      scene.add(textMesh);
      res();
    });
  });
}

const font1 = loadFont('font-path-1.json'); // Promise for first font
const font2 = loadFont('font-path-2.json'); // Promise for second font

Promise.all([font1, font2]).then(() => {
  fade_meshes_into_scene();  
})
```

Comment: Thank you! Currently at work and can't test it out (wanted to figure this out before I got home and implemented it). Will test it out asap :)